# Laravel Eloquent Triple Relation with Pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am trying to make a relation between 3 tables with pivot. I just want to make it with eloquent because of the `count()` method.

Here is my tables.

```
brands: id, name
posts: id, title
tags: id, name, brand_id (fk)
post_tag: post_id (fk), tag_id (fk)
```

Explanation:

- brand hasMany posts through tag,
- tags belongsTo Brand
- brand should select the post_id from Pivot table through the tags to get correct posts.

And in `PostsController` im getting trend tags (as Brand if tag name equals brand's name) to make an order like this

```
protected function getTrends($model)
{
    return $model::has('posts', '>=', '1')->withCount(['posts' => function($q) {
        $q->whereDate('created_at', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subWeek());
    }])->orderBy('posts_count', 'DESC')->take(10)->get();
}
```

Here is what i exactly want to do:

- First, im getting tag name and searching in brands table to get it while creating a post. After that, i'm getting posts are assigned to tags from Pivot table to make a list on posts/index page. And the tag belongs to a brand; at this point i want to get brand and show its properties. Also i need to be able to get count of posts by model as `$brand->posts()->count()` to make getTrends function work.

I tried hasManyThrough on Brand model, but it is not selecting the id from the post_tag Pivot. So it's showing me the wrong result.

I am not sure what should i do. Maybe i am making a simple mistake but i can not see it because of trying so many hours.

**EDIT**

Usage of getTrends function.

```
\\PostsController;

public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10, ['*'], 'sayfa');

    //Get Popular brands of the week by created posts count
    $popularBrands = $this->getTrends('App\Brand');

    //Get Popular products of the week by created posts count
    $popularProducts = $this->getTrends('App\Product');

    $popularPosts = Post::popularWeek()->take(10)->get();

    $data = ['posts', 'popularBrands', 'popularProducts', 'popularPosts'];
    return view('posts.index', compact($data));
}
```

That's mean products or brands can be trend as a tag.

Blade view of posts.index

```
@foreach($popularBrands as $popularBrand)
@if($popularBrand->posts_count > 0)
    <div class="col-12 {{ $loop->last ? 'mb-0' : 'mb-2' }}">
        <a href="{{ route('brand.posts', $popularBrand->slug) }}" class="row nodecoration align-items-center" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-title="{{ $popularBrand->name }}">
            <span class="col-auto col-lg p-0 text-truncate" ># {{ $popularBrand->name }}</span>
            <span class="col col-lg-auto text-right p-0 font-14 text-muted">{{ $popularBrand->posts_count }} konu</span>
        </a>
    </div>                                      
@endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Post how you're using the `getTrends` method

Comment: @CaddyDZ Post updated.

Comment: You can try Many to Many (Polymorphic) relationship.. Try this...

Comment: You can try Many to Many (Polymorphic) relationship.. Try this...

Comment: @TanvirAhmed I already tried that but it's not working as i expect.